# Customized DisplayFormatAttribute only setting once

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I am setting NullDisplayText in the DisplayFormat from resource through the following code

```
public class LocalizedDisplayFormatAttribute : DisplayFormatAttribute
{

    private readonly PropertyInfo _propertyInfo;


    public LocalizedDisplayFormatAttribute(string resourceKey, Type resourceType)
        : base()
    {
        this._propertyInfo = resourceType.GetProperty(resourceKey, BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public);
        if (this._propertyInfo == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        base.NullDisplayText = (string)this._propertyInfo.GetValue(this._propertyInfo.DeclaringType, null);
    }


    public new string NullDisplayText
    {
        get
        {
            return base.NullDisplayText;
        }

        set
        {
            base.NullDisplayText = value;
        }
    }
}
```

My default culture used is "en-US",Once I change the culture to es-AR and load the pages its working fine, but when I change the culture back to en-US fields are not getting converted back.

I change the culture throught the following way

```
protected void Application_AcquireRequestState(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            HttpCookie cookie = HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies.Get("CurrentCulture");
            string culutureCode = cookie != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(cookie.Value) ? cookie.Value : "en";
            CultureInfo ci = new CultureInfo(culutureCode);
            System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = ci;
            System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture =
            CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture(ci.Name);
        }
        catch
        {
        }
    }
```

I use DisplayFormat attribute in ViewModel as

```
  public class AlarmCodeDetailsViewModel
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets the alarm code ID
        /// </summary>
        public int AlarmCodeID { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets the alarm code
        /// </summary>
        [LocalizedDisplayName("Label_AlarmCode")]
        [LocalizedDisplayFormatAttribute("Warning_NullDisplayText", typeof(Properties.Resources), HtmlEncode = false)]
        public string Code { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets the Description
        /// </summary>
        [LocalizedDisplayName("Label_Description")]
        [LocalizedDisplayFormatAttribute("Warning_NullDisplayText", typeof(Properties.Resources), HtmlEncode = false)]
        public string Description { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets the Notes
        /// </summary>
        [LocalizedDisplayName("Label_Notes")]
        [LocalizedDisplayFormatAttribute("Warning_NullDisplayText", typeof(Properties.Resources), HtmlEncode = false)]
        public string Notes { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: how are you changing the culture? please share your approach / code for changing . And please share your code declaration of View Model with use of LocalizedDisplayFormatAttribute.

Comment: @Dave Alperovich: I have edited my question

Comment: Please help me out. I'm confused by some wording in the question. You say that **But when I change the culture it does not affecting the NullDisplayText, it's setting only once** I read that to mean that your app reads the culture setting once and sets the `NullDisplayText` once. That is probably NOT what you mean, since the culture will only be set once, so there seems to be no problem.

Comment: I'm guessing you mean the NullDisplayText should be set differently than it is. If so, please explain with greater detail. What is the culture you get and what is expected value of NullDisplayText vs value you get.

Comment: @DaveAlperovich : my default culture used is "en-US",Once i change the culture to es-AR and load the pages its working fine,but when i change the culture back to en-US fields are not getting converted back.

Comment: Ok, this is good. I understand you a little bit better. Please explain how and when are you changing the culture. Are you changing a setting in your browser so the incoming headers are changed?

Comment: @DaveAlperovich : In my application there is a option to change language,when user select and  change the language,the culture code is saved in a cookie . In Global.asax  I have added Application_AcquireRequestState (Please refer above code in question) in which culture is changed.

Comment: I see. This looks correct so far. I wonder, have you gone used the debugger or any other way to check the value of `ci.Name` ?

Comment: value changes correctly.When  I load page for the first time DisplayFormatAttribute works fine. When I reload the page after culture change Values is displayed in previous culture format. LocalizedDisplayFormatAttribute  is only called once.

Comment: Everything you have done looks correct. I suspect your Culture is being cached. Try adding overriding `GetVaryByCustomString`  in Global.asax... Or turning off output cache http://visitmix.com/writings/using-varybycustom-with-outputcache-in-asp-net-mvc-to-support-caching-for-logged-in-users

Comment: This didn't work for me.Is there any Idea to change Null to a Custom message from resource

Comment: You can use a custom route. And action filter.

Comment: may be you can get some idea from this post? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1560796/set-culture-in-an-asp-net-mvc-app 
he is using this localization method and added a route parameter that sets the culture and language

Comment: I'm looking at the MSDN and they use it like this: [DisplayFormat(ConvertEmptyStringToNull = true, NullDisplayText = "[Null]")] Have you tried the attribute similar to this?

Comment: normally it's working.When I change the culture and load that screen again. Message is shown from previous resource culture.

Comment: If you take that `try` `catch` out of `AcquireRequestState`, when you change back cultures do you get an exception?

Comment: No...culture change is working fine.

Comment: @JustinCI Unless I'm missing something, why can't you just use the `Display` attibute? `[Display(Name = "Item", ResourceType = typeof(MyResources))]`

Comment: @ mattytommo If I use Display Attribute , IAm not clear how to format NULL values

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Here's some insight into what's wrong.**

Mvc is using a form of TypeDescriptor (`AssociatedMetadataTypeTypeDescriptionProvider(type).GetTypeDescriptor(type)`) to read attributes off your models.  The TypeDescriptors are caching information about properties and attributes.  So your `LocalizedDisplayFormatAttribute` attribute is only getting instantiated once, in terms of the TypeDescriptor api's, which means that the resource information is only read once (at construction). See the bottom of the answer for references.

**Solutions that dont work**

1. The blink reaction is to just pull the latest resource information from your `LocalizedDisplayFormatAttribute NullDisplayText` every time it is accessed via the getter. Unfortunately `DisplayFormatAttribute` `NullDisplayText`is not virtual, and you are shadowing the property with a `new` keyword.  This won't work from a polymorphic dispatch perspective (Mvc is calling the getter as a `DisplayFormatAttribute` instead of a `LocalizedDisplayFormatAttribute`, so your shadowed property is never being called)
2. I tried `TypeDescriptor.Refresh()` overloads https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z1ztz056(v=vs.110).aspx and had no luck

**The remaining options that I'm aware of are not as convenient or not amazing in one way or another.  Probably not recommended.**

1. Some way to successfully refresh the `AssociatedMetadataTypeTypeDescriptionProvider TypeDescriptors`.  I'm not too familiar with these, so there could totally be one.  I'm just not seeing one currently.
2. Rework or create a `ModelMetadataProvider` of your own.  Everything is open source, so its possible, though I'm not sure I would recommend it except as a last resort.
3. You could possibly work with the TypeDescriptor api's to force a re-instantiation of your attribute whenever it is being pulled.  See https://stackoverflow.com/a/12143653/897291.
4. Model the needed properties directly in MVC (as model properties, instead of attributes).  Could either be entirely new properties, or you could have some sort of logic within your original properties, that when null return something else.  Awkward to deal with though.

Nothing great, I know.  Maybe this will give someone else enough insight to come up with something better?

**To verify this yourself, see**
https://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/System.Web.Mvc/DataAnnotationsModelMetadataProvider.cs `CreateMetaData` method which calls `SetFromDataTypeAndDisplayAttributes` method setting `result.NullDisplayText = displayFormatAttribute.NullDisplayText;`

`DataAnnotationsModelMetadataProvider` extends `AssociatedMetadataProvider` which is repsonsible for passing in the attributes.  See https://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/System.Web.Mvc/AssociatedMetadataProvider.cs `GetMetadataForProperty` method as an example.