# IExtenderProvider add just some properties depending on object type

Tags: c#, winforms, windows-forms-designer

I'm having an issue and I don't know if this is indeed doable (if there's a "hacky" way, I'm all up for it, but I haven't found one).

I have an `IExtenderProvider` component that I'm using to have my own `UITypeEditor` for some properties on third-party controls (which I can't change, for obvious reasons).

These controls don't necessarily inherit from the same base (and if they do, the base doesn't necessarily have the properties I want to extend, and those are defined in the same class).

So, imagine for example I want to make an alternative property for the properties `Image`, `Glyph`, `LargeGlyph`, `SmallGlyph` on them.

So I have something like:

```
[ProvideProperty("LargeGlyphCustom", typeof (object))]
[ProvideProperty("GlyphCustom", typeof(object))]
[ProvideProperty("SmallImageCustom", typeof(object))]
[ProvideProperty("LargeImageCustom", typeof(object))]
[ProvideProperty("ImageCustom", typeof(object))]
public class MyImageExtender : Component, IExtenderProvider
{
  private readonly Type[] _extendedTypes =
  {
    typeof (OtherControl),
    typeof (SomeOtherControl),
    typeof (AControl),
    typeof (AButton)
  };

  bool IExtenderProvider.CanExtend(object o)
  {
    if (!DesignMode) return false;
    return _extendedTypes.Any(t => t.IsInstanceOfType(o));
  } 

  // Implement the property setter and getter methods
}
```

So far, so good. I can see my properties on the controls of the types I'm expecting.

However, these are replacements (just to change the `UITypeEditor`) of properties in the control.

The problem with my approach is that I see **all** of the extended properties in **all** of the extended types.

Say, if `AButton` only has `Image`, I only want to see `ImageCustom` and not `SmallImageCustom`, `LargeImageCustom`, etc.

So my approach was to do this:

```
[ProvideProperty("LargeGlyphCustom", typeof (OtherControl))]
// other properties
[ProvideProperty("ImageCustom", typeof(AButton))]
public class MyImageExtender : Component, IExtenderProvider
// ...
```

This seemed to work fine, and now I only see `ImageCustom` on `AButton`, and `LargeGlyphCustom` on `OtherControl`.

Now the problem is, if I want to show `ImageCustom` in both `AButton` and `OtherControl`, I had thought of doing this:

```
[ProvideProperty("ImageCustom", typeof(AButton))]
[ProvideProperty("ImageCustom", typeof(OtherControl))]
public class MyImageExtender : Component, IExtenderProvider
```

This doesn't work though, I only get to see `ImageCustom` on `AButton`, but not on `OtherControl`.

Decompiling the sources for `ProvidePropertyAttribute`, the reason this happens is "arguably" clear. It internally creates a `TypeId`, which I *suspect* is what the WinForms designer is using like this:

```
public override object TypeId
{
  get
  {
    return (object) (this.GetType().FullName + this.propertyName);
  }
}
```

Which makes the TypeId be `"ProvidePropertyAttributeImageCustom"`, so it can't differentiate between the different receiver types.

<s>I'm going to test deriving `ProvidePropertyAttribute` and create a different `TypeId` since it seems overridable, but I expect the winforms designer expect the specific `ProvidePropertyAttribute` type and not a derived one (the winforms designer is picky with these things).</s>

Ouch, `ProvidePropertyAttribute` is `sealed` so I can't derive and make my custom `TypeId`, it seems (not that I had high hopes that this would work at all)

In the meantime, anyone has ever done something like this and know something I could use?

Comment: Are the controls that you want to extend, your custom controls?

Comment: @RezaAghaei nope, as stated on the question, they are third-party (and I don't have the source code)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I know this is a quick answer, but this has been driving me nuts for a few days, so I've gone a different route which seems to work just fine.

Since the target goal (as I explained on my question) was to change the `UITypeEditor` on some properties, I've made a non-visual component that overrides the attributes (using a custom `TypeDescriptor`) on those properties, and assign my custom `UITypeEditor` there.

I used [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12143653/68972) as a base for implementing the property-overriding `TypeDescriptor`.

### Update

For the record, the solution provided in the linked answer worked, however it had a problem where the `TypeDescriptionProvider` would get picked up for derived classes, however the returned `TypeDescriptor` would only return the properties for the base object (the one for which you passed in the parent `TypeDescriptor`), causing havok in things like the winforms designer.

I made an all purpose property-overrider `TypeDescriptionProvider`. So far, it has worked just fine. Here's the implementation. See the [linked answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12143653/68972) for an explanation of where did this come from:

1. The provider:

   ```
   internal class PropertyOverridingTypeDescriptionProvider : TypeDescriptionProvider
   {
       private readonly Dictionary<Type, ICustomTypeDescriptor> _descriptorCache = new Dictionary<Type, ICustomTypeDescriptor>();
       private readonly Func<PropertyDescriptor, bool> _condition;
       private readonly Func<PropertyDescriptor, Type, PropertyDescriptor> _propertyCreator;

       public PropertyOverridingTypeDescriptionProvider(TypeDescriptionProvider parentProvider, Func<PropertyDescriptor, bool> condition, Func<PropertyDescriptor, Type, PropertyDescriptor> propertyCreator) : base(parentProvider)
       {
           _condition = condition;
           _propertyCreator = propertyCreator;
       }

       public override ICustomTypeDescriptor GetTypeDescriptor(Type objectType, object instance)
       {
           lock (_descriptorCache)
           {
               ICustomTypeDescriptor returnDescriptor;
               if (!_descriptorCache.TryGetValue(objectType, out returnDescriptor))
               {
                   returnDescriptor = CreateTypeDescriptor(objectType);
               }
               return returnDescriptor;
           }
       }

       private ICustomTypeDescriptor CreateTypeDescriptor(Type targetType)
       {
           var descriptor = base.GetTypeDescriptor(targetType, null);
           _descriptorCache.Add(targetType, descriptor);
           var ctd = new PropertyOverridingTypeDescriptor(descriptor, targetType, _condition, _propertyCreator);
           _descriptorCache[targetType] = ctd;
           return ctd;
       }
   }
   ```
2. This is the actual `TypeDescriptor`:

   ```
   internal class PropertyOverridingTypeDescriptor : CustomTypeDescriptor
   {
       private readonly ICustomTypeDescriptor _parent;
       private readonly PropertyDescriptorCollection _propertyCollection;
       private readonly Type _objectType;
       private readonly Func<PropertyDescriptor, bool> _condition;
       private readonly Func<PropertyDescriptor, Type, PropertyDescriptor> _propertyCreator;

       public PropertyOverridingTypeDescriptor(ICustomTypeDescriptor parent, Type objectType, Func<PropertyDescriptor, bool> condition, Func<PropertyDescriptor, Type, PropertyDescriptor> propertyCreator)
           : base(parent)
       {
           _parent = parent;
           _objectType = objectType;
           _condition = condition;
           _propertyCreator = propertyCreator;
           _propertyCollection = BuildPropertyCollection();
       }

       private PropertyDescriptorCollection BuildPropertyCollection()
       {
           var isChanged = false;
           var parentProperties = _parent.GetProperties();

           var pdl = new PropertyDescriptor[parentProperties.Count];
           var index = 0;
           foreach (var pd in parentProperties.OfType<PropertyDescriptor>())
           {
               var pdReplaced = pd;
               if (_condition(pd))
               {
                   pdReplaced = _propertyCreator(pd, _objectType);
               }
               if (!ReferenceEquals(pdReplaced, pd)) isChanged = true;
               pdl[index++] = pdReplaced;
           }
           return !isChanged ? parentProperties : new PropertyDescriptorCollection(pdl);
       }

       public override object GetPropertyOwner(PropertyDescriptor pd)
       {
           var o = base.GetPropertyOwner(pd);
           return o ?? this;
       }

       public override PropertyDescriptorCollection GetProperties()
       {
           return _propertyCollection;
       }
       public override PropertyDescriptorCollection GetProperties(Attribute[] attributes)
       {
           return _propertyCollection;
       }
   }
   ```

And here's how you use it. I've commented this:

```
private void ChangeTypeProperties(Type modifiedType, params string[] propertyNames)
{
    // Get the current TypeDescriptionProvider
    var curProvider = TypeDescriptor.GetProvider(modifiedType);
    // Create a replacement provider, pass in the parent, this is important
    var replaceProvider = new PropertyOverridingTypeDescriptionProvider(curProvider,
        // This the predicate that says wether a `PropertyDescriptor` should be changed
        // Here we are changing only the System.Drawing.Image properties,
        // either those whose name we pass in, or all if we pass none
        pd =>
            typeof (System.Drawing.Image).IsAssignableFrom(pd.PropertyType) &&
            (propertyNames.Length == 0 || propertyNames.Contains(pd.Name)),

        // This our "replacer" function. It'll get the source PropertyDescriptor and the object type.
        // You could use pd.ComponentType for the object type, but I've
        // found it to fail under some circumstances, so I just pass it
        // along
        (pd, t) =>
        {
            // Get original attributes except the ones we want to change
            var atts = pd.Attributes.OfType<Attribute>().Where(x => x.GetType() != typeof (EditorAttribute)).ToList();
            // Add our own attributes
            atts.Add(new EditorAttribute(typeof (MyOwnEditor), typeof (System.Drawing.Design.UITypeEditor)));
            // Create the new PropertyDescriptor
            return TypeDescriptor.CreateProperty(t, pd, atts.ToArray());
        }
    );
    // Finally we replace the TypeDescriptionProvider
    TypeDescriptor.AddProvider(replaceProvider, modifiedType);
}
```

Now, for the requirements of my question, I've created a simple drop-in component which I drop on the base form, which does just this:

```
public class ToolbarImageEditorExtender : Component
{
    private static bool _alreadyInitialized;
    public ToolbarImageEditorExtender()
    {
        // no need to reinitialize if we drop more than one component
        if (_alreadyInitialized)
            return;
        _alreadyInitialized = true;
        // the ChangeTypeProperties function above. I just made a generic version
        ChangeTypeProperties<OtherControl>(nameof(OtherControl.Glyph), nameof(OtherControl.LargeGlyph));
        ChangeTypeProperties<AButton>(nameof(AButton.SmallImage), nameof(AButton.LargeImage));
        // etc.
    }
}
```

So far, it has worked wonders.